# How to get text by class name from a website using chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get text from a website using chrome extension. The text is updated automatically from the website. Below is my popup.js file's code

```
let changeColor = document.getElementById('Start');
    chrome.storage.sync.get('color', function(data) {
        changeColor.style.backgroundColor = data.color;
        changeColor.setAttribute('value', data.color);
      });

      changeColor.onclick = function(element) {
        let color = element.target.value;
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "inject.js" });
        });
        });
      };
```

And the inject.js code

```
    var asd =  $(".txt-big ng-binding :first").text();
    console.log(asd); // get nothing here
    $(".txt-big ng-binding :first").change(function(){
    console.log($(".txt-big ng-binding").text()); // it doesn't get executed
    });
```

For the first console.log is empty.

And for second console.log I get noting.
How do get I apply change method and get value when ever it changed ?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Typo. You need to add `()` at the end of `.text` to actually invoke the function. Right now `asd` holds a *reference* to the method, not it's return value.

Comment: Thanx there was a typo I changed the question a little. But still I am getting empty log here.

Comment: `ng-binding` is not a valid HTML element. I'm assuming you're using Angular, as such you need to select elements in the HTML *output*, not the pre-processed Angular statements.

Comment: ok I remove ng-binding and add .eq(1) the first log is working and added  $(".txt-big").on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){ which replaces .change function

Answer (score 0):

I change a code a bit .change function is for inputs radio button etc

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var asd =  $(".txt-big").eq(1).text();
    console.log(asd);
    $(".txt-big").on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
      console.log("eeff");
    });
  });
```